# Get enum index from string

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get the index integer (in this case 0) from an enum when I have a string to compare against the enum?

Enum:

```
public enum Animals
{
    Dog = 0,
    Cat = 1
}

string myAnimal = "Dog";
```

Obviously the following line won't work but it might help you to understand what I want to achieve:

```
int animalNumber = (int)Animals.[myAnimal];
```

Comment: Possible of duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778213/get-an-enumerated-field-from-a-string?rq=1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like this?

```
int animalNumber = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(Animals), "Dog");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Types t;
if(Enum.TryParse(yourString, out t)) // yourString is "Dog", for example
{
    // use t           // In your case (int)t
}
else
{
    // yourString does not contain a valid Types value
}
```

OR

```
try
{
    Types t = (Types)Enum.Parse(typeof(Types), yourString);
    // use t           // In your case (int)t
}
catch(ArgumentException)
{
    // yourString does not contain a valid Types value
}
```